# AWS CDK synth and deploy from JAR file

Tags: aws-cdk

I order to treat my Infrastructure as code I would like to create a pipeline where my app code (let's say some lambda functions) are compiled, packaged and uploaded/deployed with a respective version to my Artifacts repo (CodeArtifact) INCLUDING my CDK app.

Then, In a following step in the pipeline I would like to download the JARs from the Artifacts repo, and run a 'cdk synth/deploy' from the previously generated JAR.

Is it possible to execute cdk synth/deploy passing a jar reference/path instead of from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as executeting the generated shadow file.

```
java -jar path/your-app-all.jar
```

This can be place in the cdk.json file, then execute cdk synth or cdk deploy as always.

```
{
  "app": "java -jar ./build/libs/infrastructure-all.jar"
}
```

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful if 1. you explained what you mean by shadow file.  Google gives pretty much only this answer.  2. You explained it with context about cdk.  E.g. "run cdk synth at build time, add this to your cdk.json (then cdk picks it up when you run xxx) and run cdk deploy at deploy time".